# React Native Firebase how to fetch data from array of tables with specific user

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

[image: Db Scheme]

I am taking "userId" from tutor table (of specific user) and on basis of that userId a table is created under "tutorCopy" and those users who accepts the services of "john@john.com" saves its userId and useremail. Now when john@john.com logs into the system I want to show the number of email/persons assigned to him.
This is what I've done so far, but I can't reach to useremail:

```
 componentWillMount(){
     var refx =firebase.database().ref("tutorCopy")
    refx.orderByChild("table").on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            this.setState({ markers: Object.values(snapshot.val()) })
          //alert(data.useremail)
        });
      });
    }
```

Also I only want to show useremail of only those with tutorId matches from tutor table to tutorCopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 componentWillMount(){
     var refx =firebase.database().ref("tutorCopy")
    refx.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
          childSnapshot.forEach((childSnap) =>{
           console.log(childSnap.val());
          });
        });
      });
    }
```

You need to iterate twice to access the `useremail`, also `orderByChild("table")` will not work in this case because you cannot access the `table` node since you  need to go one node further, example:

```
var refx =firebase.database().ref("tutorCopy")
refx.child(userId).orderByChild("table")
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! that actually worked but when I setSatete  of markers to childSnap it gives me error: Can't read property 'setState'

Comment: How can I setState of markers to childSnap, it always says cannot setState markers is null

Comment: im not sure why you are getting this error, have you used `setState` somewhere else in your app?

Comment: Yes in another class but its working fine over there.., this might cos of nested tables in firebase , even i initialize markers as array in state.